# evaluating $ \int\limits _{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+\varepsilon}}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, perturbation-theory

I came across this : 
I'm trying to evaluate it up to $ o(\epsilon) $
$$ F\left(\varepsilon\right)=\int\limits _{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+\varepsilon}} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

I've trying considering to look at it as the following
$$ F\left(\varepsilon\right)=\int\limits _{0}^{\theta}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+\varepsilon}} \, \mathrm{d}x+\int\limits _{\theta}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+\varepsilon}}\, \mathrm{d}x
 $$

and evaluate each integral separately and hoping that the intermediate region will cancel out (this method is widely used in perturbation theory to evaluate integrals) but I can't seem to find the right way to evaluate the first integral...

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: My idea: it is not that hard to see that $(x+\varepsilon)^{-1/2}=x^{-1/2} -\frac{\varepsilon}{2 x^{3/2}} + o(\varepsilon x^{-3/2})$. This is a useful approximation for large $x$. So choose a splitting point $\theta$. Then approximate the integral on $[\theta,1]$ as I described above, and approximate the integral on $[0,\theta]$ using the simple fact that it is between $0$ and $2\sqrt{\theta}$. Now the part I'm not so sure about (which is why I'm not writing an answer) is how to nicely choose $\theta$ to make this a useful approximation.

Comment: (Cont.) You need $\theta$ so large that $\varepsilon \theta^{-3/2}$ is small, but you also need it so small that $2\sqrt{\theta}$ is a good estimate for the integral on $[0,\theta]$. So there is a balance to be struck. And I'm not sure how that balance is going to get the $-2\sqrt{\varepsilon}$ term from the Taylor approximation of the explicit solution.

Comment: @Ian That a good way of thinking, but as you said, the tricky part is for $ [0,\theta] $ for that region im stuck with how to expand the expression to get a solution that is allso $ \varepsilon^{2}\theta^{-\frac{3}{2}} $

Comment: Another thought: as you can see from the explicit solution, $\int_\varepsilon^1 x^{-1/2} dx$ is a $O(\varepsilon)$ approximation. There are two pieces to its error: $\int_0^\varepsilon (x+\varepsilon)^{-1/2}$ and $\int_\varepsilon^1 (x+\varepsilon)^{-1/2}-x^{-1/2} dx$. Somehow there is some cancellation between these two errors, because the first error is on the order of $\varepsilon^{1/2}$, which means the second one must also be of the same order and with a coefficient of the opposite sign.

Comment: Thats exactly what i expect, 
My problem is just figuring out how to evaluate the first region integral.
it cannot be expanded around x=0 ... 
$ \int\limits _{0}^{\theta}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+\epsilon}}dx =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}\int\limits _{0}^{\theta}1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{\varepsilon}+\frac{3}{8}\left(\frac{x}{ \epsilon}\right)^{2}+O\left(\left(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}\right)^{3}\right)dx  $

Comment: Continue: 
but as you can see i will get orders of $ \frac{\theta}{\epsilon} $ which is no good if i want it to cancel out with the second part integral

Comment: Well, $(x+\varepsilon)^{-1/2}=x^{-1/2}-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}x^{-3/2}+C(x,\varepsilon) \varepsilon^2x^{-5/2}$; we should have that $C$ is bounded uniformly in $\varepsilon$ for $x$ bounded away from zero. Unfortunately, the result of integrating that (subtracting $x^{-1/2}$) is not very good, because the antiderivative of the last term when you plug in $\varepsilon$ is $O(\sqrt{\varepsilon})$. And I'm not sure how to do any better, because you pick up a power of $\varepsilon$ in both the numerator and denominator at each stage of expansion.

Comment: Maybe you can make the splitting point some lower order power of $\varepsilon$ like $\varepsilon^{1/2}$. Because $(\varepsilon^{1/2})^{-3/2}=\varepsilon^{-3/4}$ and then $2-3/4=5/4$ which is bigger than $1$.

Comment: that no problem, maybe just forget about it, i denoted it $ \theta $ and ill pick later, it just need to hold that $ 1 \gg  \theta \gg \epsilon $ 
the problem is that te expansion you offers explodes when u integrate and substitut 0 in it...

Comment: Well, let's try $\theta=\sqrt{\varepsilon}$. Then $\int_{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+\varepsilon}}$ can be Taylor approximated in the way I described, since $\varepsilon (\varepsilon^{1/2})^{-1/2}=\varepsilon^{3/4}$ and $\varepsilon^2 (\varepsilon^{1/2})^{-3/2}=\varepsilon^{5/4}$. Then you just need to deal with the $[0,\sqrt{\varepsilon}]$ piece, which should be doable.

Comment: @Ian thanks alot, and  Yep as i trying explaning before, 
My problem is with the integral for $ [0,\sqrt(\epsilon)] $ ( or any other $ \theta $ , maybe you have any tips for that?

Comment: Well, one way would be to note that $x+\varepsilon \geq \min \{ x,\varepsilon \}$. So $\int_0^{\sqrt{\varepsilon}} \frac{1}{(x+\varepsilon)^{1/2}} dx \leq \int_0^\varepsilon x^{-1/2} dx + \int_\varepsilon^{\sqrt{\varepsilon}} \varepsilon^{-1/2} dx=2\sqrt{\varepsilon}+1-\sqrt{\varepsilon}$. This should be fairly tight. Try to play with the errors here and see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

We have that $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+\varepsilon}} \, \mathrm{d}x = 2\left(\sqrt{\varepsilon + 1} - \sqrt{\varepsilon}\right).$$

Since we can write $1/\sqrt{x+\varepsilon} = (x+\varepsilon)^{-1/2}$ and use the reverse chain rule.

Comment: thanks for the advice but i need to evaluate without explicitly solving :D

Comment: @Simba You can do a series representation of the right side and get the final result that you want. In particular you have $\sqrt{\varepsilon+1}=1+\frac{\varepsilon}{2} + o(\varepsilon)$, so that the integral is $2-2\sqrt{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon+o(\varepsilon)$.

Comment: @Ian the idea is to evaluate it without solving the integral.
you can expand the integrand and solve polinomial expression but not solve it directly...